# When I ran Ubuntu's apt-get, something went wrong, and now I can't install or change any software package

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Screen Shot]

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
When I try to update my OS, this is the second time that I have ever encountered this mistake, the last time I reinstall the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, the -f shouldn't be there after the install command ... 
try the following first

```
sudo apt-get install
```

instead

If it's not working, answer here please and I try to help more

Edit: For updates only you should use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first, and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after that